Configure Keycloack with Spring Security
I have no Idea how to configure Spring Boot 3, Spring Security 6 with Keycloack. Whatever I tried, it always redirect to main page, shows White Page with 403 or it is imposibble to logout. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I also use thymeleaf, it's standard Spring MVC app.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableMethodSecurity
class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    fun configure(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http
            .cors {
                it.disable()
            }
            .oauth2Login {  }
            .oauth2Client {  }
            .logout {  }
            .authorizeHttpRequests { authorize ->
                authorize
                    .requestMatchers(
                        "/portal/**",
                    ).authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
            }
            .sessionManagement {
                it.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            }
        return http.build()
    }
}

The configuration above always redirect to the main page

the issue is with permitAll()

what exactly the issue is?

your allowing unrestricted access for any request, meaning if they try and access a route with required authentication, the fallback will always be main page

this is expected behaviour, so whats the issue exactly?
